# Spring Boot Data JPA NULL values for nested entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There are 5 entities and respective JPA repository for them. Implemented on service class and controller to POST the data in Database.

**Database mapping and structure is :**

Entity 2,3,5 have **one to one** relationship (mapping) with Entity 1.

Entity 3 and 4 have **one to many**

Below is the request body format.

```
{
    "prpoperty1": "",
    "prpoperty2": "",   entity1 (main)
    "prpoperty3": " ",
    "entity2": {
        "prpoperty1": "",
        "prpoperty2": "",
    },
    "entity3": {
        "prpoperty1": "",
        "prpoperty2": ""  
        "entity4": [
            {
                "prpoperty1": "", **(NULL IN DATA BASE)**
                "prpoperty2": ""  **(NULL IN DATA BASE)**
            },
            {
                "prpoperty1": "", (NULL IN DATA BASE)
                "prpoperty1": "" (NULL IN DATA BASE)
            }
        ]
    },
    "entity5": {
        "prpoperty1": "",
        "prpoperty1": "",       
    }
}
```

In service class using entity1 to set and save the data.(a snippet from that class)

```
@Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Object> storeSomething(Entity1 entity){

        Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
        entity1.set...(entity.get...());
        entity1.set....(entity.get.....());
        

        ServiceR sObj = sRepository.save(entity1);
        if (sRepository.findById(sObj.getId()).isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.accepted().body("Successfully Created ");
        } else
        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body("Failed to Create");
    }
```

**My question is** : How to store values for entity 4 in given request body format?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using mapping DTO to entity.